# How to translate Grid without knowing the size of the surrounding container

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone-8, storyboard

I'm working on a windows phone 8.1 project.
I'm trying to perform an animation of my grid.
Let's see the code first.

```
<Page
x:Class="CityBoxApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:CityBoxApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Grid Background="#353C3F">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Text="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="35" FontStyle="Italic"/>
        <Grid Height="15"
          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
          Background="#EC641A"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Border BorderBrush="Snow" BorderThickness="3" Padding="20, 40, 20, 40">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Width="280" Content="Search around me" Margin="0, 0, 0 ,25"/>
                <Button Width="280" Content="Search with an address"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
 </Grid>
</Page>
```

I've been looking at lots of stuff on google but basically the problem is that the main grid always has a size in those cases. What i'm trying to perform is basically to translate my grid  (Grid.Row 1) from outside of the screen from the right to the middle of the screen like it is now. What i would like it to be able to do something that would fit any size of screen. Any advice/example or documentation on this precise subject ?

Thank you guys a lot!

Comment: 8.1 Silverlight or 8.1 XAML?

Comment: That's 8.1 XAML @IgorKulman